# Use different font when Zooming in in Firefox

Tags: firefox

When I zoom in using Firefox, I would like to change the font used on the site to Georgia because it looks better in larger size. Is there a Firefox extension or javascript I can use to make this happen? Or attach the Zoom keyboard hotkey to a user defined css file maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I think the difficulty you're going to run into, unfortunately, is that it is difficult, if not impossible, to [tell what zoom level the browser is at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript) using straight up javascript.

That said, the flash plugin, which most people have, [seems to have a way](http://novemberborn.net/2007/12/javascriptpage-zoom-ff3-128) ([demo](http://tests.novemberborn.net/browsers/gecko/fullzoom/flash.html)).

If you can get a change in that value to trigger a function (not sure if that's possible, but I'm guessing it is), you can just set that function to change the font-type of class foobar to Georgia.

Comment: There's no need to find the zoom level. When I hit ctrl++, I want a different font to be used interactively.

Comment: What about when you hit ctrl and then scroll in with the mouse wheel?