# CSS Container/Text auto resizing

Tags: css

i am currently building a website using HTML and and external CSS Stylesheet. I have a "container" which holds the content of my page, central to the body. What i want is that when a user adjusts the text size using there browser that the "container" automatically resizes with the text so that it stays in proportion. At the moment the text size changes but the container doesn't. I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance

Matt

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in IE, in other browsers e.g. Firefox, the containers will be correctly resized.

You would need to detect the browser type; then if it's IE use some fancy javascript workarounds to get it to work.

[Catch browser's "zoom" event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript)