# Disable div background resizing when zooming page

Tags: css

I have a webpage that consist of 4 different div elements set in columns. 
The page have no scrolling so all content is on screen. My question is how to
disable div backrounds zooming when zooming content because it ruins the page
structure. And ofcourse that should work in eveycase because I'm using different
backround sizes trought Media Queries.
My fist question is is that possible anyway, and will it work in IE8.

CODE:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
    <div id="div4"></div>
</div>

<div id="container">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
    <div id="div4"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
#container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%; height:100%;
    border-spacing: 1px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;
}

#container > div {
    display: table-cell;
    padding:0px;
}

body,html{ height:100%; width:100%; overflow:hidden; }

#div1{ position:relative;   
         background-image:url(../images/bg/left.jpg);
         background-size: cover;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
  }
#div2{height:100%;
     background-image:url(../images/bg/center.jpg);
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     position:relative;
  }

#div3{height:100%; 
    background-image:url(../images/bg/right.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
    position:static;    
  }

#div4{ height:100%; 
     background-image:url(../images/bg/right2.jpg);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:100% cover; 
 position: static;
 background-repeat:no-repeat; 
   }
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it. Try reading this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458793/can-i-stop-the-resizing-of-elements-on-zoom

Answer (score 0):

To make the div size invariant of zooming (But not contents inside it) do the following :
Inside your css for that div :

min-width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;

This will freeze the width, you can do the same for height too.