# zoom-in messes the page structure

Tags: html, css

I always wondered what is the "secret" of well structured site.

In my site, when I zoom-in the look is getting messed up, in well preform site the the look stays the same as it was when the zoom was 100%.

**www.ebay.com when zoomed-in:**
[image: www.ebay.com when zoomed-in]

**my site, [www.livesite.co.il](http://www.livesite.co.il) when zoomed-it(and its just a little portion):**
[image]

How can I achieve that?

I know it have something to do with the structure of the site.

- I used % (tried to) on every element, isn't it suppose to be the right way?

Comment: There can be a number of reasons. Float messes up the most page structure while zooming.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287703/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-certain-screen-zoom-level-its-messing-my-site-up/7287882#7287882)

Answer (score 0):

you might be able to do something with CSS media queries. OR trying implementing a responsive template. Something like this:

```
/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am trying to figure up what I didn't do.. I really tried here to give all element the "best properties" i don't want to achieve this by workarround