# javascript event for a mobile pinch/zoom action

Tags: javascript, mobile

I need some help. I am trying to work on a mobile web page. What i'm trying to do is "capture" when the user does a zoom in/zoom out action. That is, when they put two fingers on screen and separate or close their fingers together. I looked at jquery mobile and didn't see it.

So specifically can I attach a javascript function to a pinch/zoom event in a mobile device?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at this? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

hammer.js https://hammerjs.github.io/ is one of the best javascript library for such problems..

Answer (score 3):

[Zepto](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto) is a jquery compatible library for mobile and provides handlers for pinch events. Unfortunately, they are listed as iOS only.  (See "Touch Events")

Synopsis:

```
$('some selector').pinch(function(){ ... });
$('some selector').pinchIn(function(){ ... });
$('some selector').pinchOut(function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 2):

[Touchy](http://github.com/hotstudio/touchy) is a jQuery plugin that provides support for pinch, drag, swipe, longpress, rotate.  It works on any browser that implements touchstart, touchmove and touchend.  Future versions will also support IE10.