# how to do pinching inorder to zoomin and zoomout an image in asp.net framework and HTML5?

Tags: asp.net, html, jquery-mobile

I am working on an ipad application.I am using asp.net framework with HTML5 and mobileJquery. Is there anyway to do this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to add pinch zoom, you need to have a viewport tag like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The old recommended way was:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

More information on this here: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/06/20/jquery-mobile-beta-1-released/

Also, another similar post here: [javascript event for a mobile pinch/zoom action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509799/javascript-event-for-a-mobile-pinch-zoom-action)

Comment: thanks shanabus.I have tried using the meta tag but then also i was not able to do pinching.

Answer (score 0):

Pinching can be affected by the `user-scalable` and `maximum-scale` values of your view port meta tag. Try the below line and let me know it works for you or not.
 `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.6,user-scalable=yes">`