# How to find pinch in or pinch out using Gestures events in IOS safari in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I want to implement Pinch In and Out functionality for IPAD. I've been using this events listed on http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html.

```
$('div.mainContainer').live("gesturestart", function(e){
   alert("start " + e.originalEvent.scale);
});
$('div.mainContainer').live("gesturechange", function(e){
   alert("change " + e.originalEvent.scale);
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

The above code works but could not figure out the pinch in/out.

P.S. I've tried [jGestures](http://jgestures.codeplex.com/) but it does not work at all.

Comment: just noticed the ps, what problem did you have?

Comment: as per the jgestures documentation, no event gets triggered. I tried all the events.

Comment: have you looked at the examples [here](http://abelboy.coolpage.biz/tests/jgestures/), use a tablet and go to that sight, everything works

Comment: yes, it did work but pinch out behaves abnormally - it does not invoke the callback even though a page gets zoom in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems duplicate of

[javascript event for a mobile pinch/zoom action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509799/javascript-event-for-a-mobile-pinch-zoom-action)

also look at

http://chillburn.com.au/blog/enabling-the-pinch-zoom-for-the-ipad-iphone-while-using-jquery-mobile/

and

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW8

Comment: Thanks for zepto link. The other  two links  are  out of the context of the question.