# pinch/pull touchevents in mobile webapp

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, touch-event

How do I register an pinch or pull event in an mobile webapp.
Is it build in the browser (if so, how can I acces it) or there an jQuery-plugn for this

(using HTML5, jQuery en jQuery mobile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://jgestures.codeplex.com/.

(Also, just Google 'jquery gestures')

Related questions:

[Catch browser's "zoom" event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript)

[javascript event for a mobile pinch/zoom action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509799/javascript-event-for-a-mobile-pinch-zoom-action)

Answer (score 0):

[Touchy](http://github.com/hotstudio/touchy) is jQuery plugin that provides support for pinch (in or out), swipe, drag, longpress, and rotate across all browsers that support the touchstart, touchmove and touchend events.