# Image alternatives in case of zoom in browser

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser, zooming

If the browser have been zoomed in the images get blured.
If I put a bigger image and set width/height to the desired size the image will be better in zoom, however in 100% some get moire, so I need some of the images to be different by the zoom level of the browser.

Is there any CSS keyword for a zoom alternative stylesheet or, zoom alternative image?

Comment: “however in 100% some get moire” — I don’t quite understand what you mean by this bit.

Comment: Your current approach is, as far as I know, the only way to make images look better when zoomed. It’s covered well here: http://www.webkit.org/blog/55/high-dpi-web-sites/. Sadly there’s not yet a CSS media query that detects the browser’s zoom level.

Comment: I have a website, and an image on it. The image is let's say 125x125 pixel. I show it with <img ... width='100' height='100'> if the browser's zoom level is '100%', the image will showed up in 100x100, so it's scaled down, and the moire happens there.

Comment: ah, like [moiré pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) — gotcha, understood.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a CSS keyword that handles browser zoom. You can use JavaScript to try to detect if the user has zoomed:

See answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/995967/1145390