# Zoom event on an element of a web page

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, zooming

How to detect zoom event (using multitouchale divice) on an element of a webpage and handle it?
Thanks for help!

Comment: Please check out this [QUESTION][1] , I believe this will answer yours.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

This type of zoom is handled internally by the browser and is not scriptable.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to implement zoom-like behavior (in plain JavaScript) in place of handing it to the browser, you need to handle [multi] touchstart/touchmove events yourself. Here's the [touch event specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/) it's pretty comprehensive.