# Resizing pop up window to zoom levels

Tags: javascript, html, css

We built a broadcast player that pops-up with the window.open script:

onclick="window.open('Media-player.html','player','scrollbars=0,width=360,height=655')"

The problem is, when someone zooms into the the player (or the parent frame for that matter) the pop-up window does not resize with it and the player overlaps within the window and some parts become hidden.

Is there any way to resize the window to fit it's contents when users zoom in? Would like to avoid enabling the scroll bars or just making the dimensions bigger.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to know if a user has zoomed the browser, but there are some tricks to try to detect it.

See this thread: [Catch browser's "zoom" event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript)

Comment: Darn. Don't think this will help as most users will zoom into the parent page and not the pop-up window. Thx

Comment: When you zoom, it often zoom's on the domain.  Meaning, any page hosted on that domain will appear zoomed, even after you navigate to a new page.  Either way, there isn't any way to KNOW that someone zoomed, only to make reasonable assumptions as suggested in that other thread.