# how to get GWT RequiresResize.onResize to respond to zooming?

Tags: gwt, resize

onResize is not called after zooming.

Current GWT implementation:

```
public native void initWindowResizeHandler() /*-{
    var oldOnResize = $wnd.onresize;
    $wnd.onresize = $entry(function(evt) {
      try {
        @com.google.gwt.user.client.Window::onResize()();
      } finally {
        oldOnResize && oldOnResize(evt);
      }
    });
  }-*/;
```

The only solutions I found for [capturing resize events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript) use polling.

1. Is polling the best (only) way? If so, how can the Scheduler be used for optimal performance?
2. Once the event is captured, does calling com.google.gwt.user.client.Window::onResize() seem like a good idea?

Thanks

***Current solution*** looking for improvements

```
@Override
  protected void onLoad() {

    Scheduler.get().scheduleFixedDelay(new RepeatingCommand() {

      @Override
      public boolean execute() {

        if (listOuter.getOffsetWidth() != knownWidth)
          onResize();

        return SomeListViewImpl.this.isAttached();
      }
    }, 200);

  }
```

onResize is called on Window.onresize and on zooming.

```
 @Override
  public void onResize() {

    knownWidth = listOuter.getOffsetWidth();
    GWT.log("resize: " + knownWidth);

    //some magic

  }
```

Comment: on which browser this is not working for you. In general capturing a resize works fine for me

Comment: I've only tried it on Chrome for mac; and it looks like "there's no way to actively detect if there's a zoom." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript