# Is there a reliable way to detect zoom of browser (not resize while viewing, but prior to viewing page)?

Tags: javascript, zooming

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript) question from '09, but I was hoping there might be a more recent answer.

I've got a JS popup setup to work for set size elements within, but, when the user is viewing sites at a higher zoom, my elements fall out of the popup. If not a way to detect zoom, is there another way to handle this issue?

Thanks!