# How to bind a function to browser Zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know it's possible to bind on re-size with:

> $(window).bind('resize', myFunction)

However

> $(window).bind('zoom', myFunction)

Does not work. The event I am trying to bind on is when you zoom and make text bigger cmd + or ctrl + . Anyone how to bind to that event? Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript

Comment: Looks like an exact dup to me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript