# How can my webpage tell if the user has enlarged their view?

Tags: javascript, web, accessibility, sizing

I am trying to detect if the user of a web application has hit `command +` (say if they are on a Mac) or otherwise instructed their browser to enlarge the view in their browser.

Is there a standard way to do this with JavaScript?

Comment: That's called zoom.  It is not easy to detect.

Comment: Not easy, or impossible?

Comment: See some of these links:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Okay having reviewed the various options it seems that by using a combination of the browser's onResize() event and [Tom Bigelajzen's fork of Yonathan Randolph's 'detect zoom' script](https://github.com/tombigel/detect-zoom) does what I need.