# Mobile site - Specific non-zoomable area

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

I have developed a toolbar that is included on quite a few sites (company wants to promote their other web properties) at runtime via jQuery. Now they want a mobile version. Everything seems good until I start thinking about what this toolbar does on a non-mobile website. They would like the toolbar version to be driven by device, not by site... so if looking at a non-mobile optimized site, they would still like for you to get a mobile optimized toolbar, at least until more sites are optimized.

I know I'm explaining this badly... so, here's a picture:
[image: sample page layout]

Is such a layout even possible? Can you specify a section of a page to me non-zoomable, while leaving the rest of the page to behave normally? Can you set the scaling of an element, just like you can set the viewport scaling of an entire site?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware (I've worked with mobile browsers), you can only enable or disable zooming for the entire page, not single elements.

The only thing I can think of is to try and catch resize/zoom events in Javascript and try to adjust the element when they are triggered, see this post I found: [Catch browser's "zoom" event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript)

But I have not tested this personally, and it sounds like a lot of work - particularly since Javascript support differs very much among themobile browsers.