# Crystal Report Viewer gets bigger than expected with browser's zoom

Tags: browser, crystal-reports

Does anybody know the way in which I can fix the size of a Crystal Report Viewer so it does not get bigger or smaller when the user makes zoom in the browser? I need that report to stay adapted to that zoom level and not get unbounded.

Any help will be appreciated as I have spent days trying this.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="True"
            Height="900px" Width="680px" EnableViewState="False" HasZoomFactorList="False"
            BestFitPage="False" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to re-size the viewer via JavaScript after the user adjusts the zoom.  This is not trivial.  See [Catch browser's “zoom” event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript).