# How to prevent images from resizing while changing the browser zoom by "Ctrl -" or "Ctrl +"?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using a jQuery plugin for slider and want the slider images to remain unchanged if we change browser's dimensions. The website below is the inspiration for the effects.

[www.beoplay.com](http://www.beoplay.com)

Comment: Don't do that, it's bad usability practice, your inspiration also allows me to zoom btw.

Comment: It is the requirement actually.

Comment: please refrain from just posting a link to your website as it usually gets you a flag and the question closed. The question is also tricky to understand because in the title you talk about zoom and in the question you talk about the browser dimension (which I assume is the viewport)

Comment: Have you tried using media queries?? - @sheebayousuf

Comment: novice user uno, thanks for the advice. I actually use ctrl -- to see the effects.@sulfureous

Comment: Then google it and use media queries only specific to your issue i.e slider. - @sheebayousuf

Comment: @NathanLee i am not talking about responsiveness indeed images should remain unaffected by pressing ctrl-- or ++.

Comment: If the user decides to zoom the whole page in/out, then the user _wants_ to zoom _everything_ – so this “requirement” should just be rejected as invalid.

Comment: But the responsiveness is the only way by which you can keep your images unaffected when the user zooms in or zooms out. You don't have to apply responsiveness to the whole part just to the images only.- @sheebayousuf

Comment: yes Nathan Lee you are right, i was confused a bit over it.

Comment: i hope i can get away with the nightmare, going try your suggested link, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fix or freeze images, just give %age value of those image in pixels. This will keep it fixed irrespective of zoom in or zoom out.

You can use [This tool](http://pixelperc.com/) to convert your pixels into percentage.

Hope I hope this helps.

**EDIT : Alternative solution**

I suggest you to use [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).
It will enable you to make the images to stay intact depending on the responsiveness.

You should apply media queries relevant to the images in issue.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I believe that this (Question) probably applies to the browser zoom-in level, not the browser window size dimension

Comment: Well I answered keeping in mind the browser zoom level, as %age dimensions shall make the images to stay intact. - @MichaelDurrant

Comment: i too think same Nathan, media query is the solution.

Comment: Yes - @sheebayousuf Media query and Pixels to percentage conversion both.

Answer (score 3):

There is no surefire way of doing this. The only suggestions that I could make will require extensive programming knowledge in javascript and even then, there is no guarantee this will work. Unless it breaks the page, I don't think you need to worry about this.
Moreover you might just kill the user's experience by trying to prevent him from rescaling
You can check this question for some solutions that *might* and I say this with a packet of salt *might* help

[Catch browser's "zoom" event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome/webkit based browsers you can try `zoom: reset;` CSS rule

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-SW15

You can also try adding viewport relative units to your elements. https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score -1):

if you want to keep the size of images fixed u can simply use css to  keep width and height fixed ,also you can set the position as fixed which will help you to to keep the image from movement.

hope it helped