# how to relocate a fixed control on zoom

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning, zooming

I have a textBox with a CSS class that specified a fixed position. I have a dropDown menu with another fixed position in a differnt CSS class. I am intentionally overlapping the controls. When I zoom in and out on the browser page, the controls stay fixed but the layout of the remaining page no longer makes sense. Is there a way to dynamically changed the fixed location (top and left values) of the CSS classes on a browser zoom event?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. There is no browser zoom event.

Probably the closest approach is one documented in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript)