# jQuery offset().top gives weird results when zooming in/out

Tags: jquery, window-resize

See my example here: http://codepen.io/comatory/pen/EyBKNv

When I collapse the page, the container moves and gives me updated value of `offset().top` however when I zoom in using my keyboard with CMD and +, it changes slightly at 90% but it stays the same more or less.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

It's expected behavior of browsers. 
Quoting from http://api.jquery.com/offset/

> ... Also, dimensions may be incorrect when the page is zoomed by the user;
>   browsers do not expose an API to detect this condition.

I dont know, but it will be very hard to make a script, which will solve that. However, to catch `zoom` events, you can look through:

- [Catch browser's "zoom" event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript)

- [How to detect page zoom level in all modern browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713771/how-to-detect-page-zoom-level-in-all-modern-browsers)

- https://gist.github.com/kevingessner/5598913