# trigger an event at certain zoom level

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I work on a map with leaflet, I want a certain level of zomme its declache a event this avenemet is to appear an image on the map

```
function initialisation() {

  var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([49.621522, 5.863455],13)// carte map et 13 c'est le zoom
  var marker = L.marker([49.621522, 5.863455]).addTo(mymap).on('click', onClick);//déclaration de la varibale Marker pour tracer une place sur Map;  

function onClick() 
  {scene(L, mymap, currentPoint);}

function scene(L, mymap, currentPoint) {

  $.getJSON('data/emplacement.json', function(data){//data c'est la liste
  for (let objet of data) { // une boucle parcour la liste des objets JSON
```

JSON picture contains some image I want a certain level of zoom his release the scene function

I did not know what I'm going to put a loop for the creation of layers

Comment: Did you check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript/6085253)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the event `zoomend` and then get the zoom level and do what you want after.

```
mymap.on('zoomend', function() {
    let zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    if (zoomLevel === 13) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaflet has a way to get the level of zoom how is explained [here](https://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels/) in their documentation. So basically you should be able to get the zoom level in which you want to dispatch the action you mention.

Comment: YES my zoom level is well defined 13 ;; var mymap = L.map ('mapid'). SetView ([49.621522, 5.863455], 13) ;; but I do not know how I trigger the event