# Detect if page is zoomed

Tags: javascript, css, zooming, gesture

Is there any way to know, at a given moment, if the page is currently zoomed-in?

**I don't need to know the zoom level**, and **I don't need to catch the event**: I simply need a **cross browser solution that allows to know if the page is zoomed or not** (e.g. a function that returns true or false). Unfortunately the solutions that I have found are completely outdated or work only on some browsers.

I need that in order to block gesture detection while the page is zoomed.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch browser's "zoom" event in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript)

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.sitelint.com/blog/detect-browser-zoom-level/

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple ways a browser can zoom. It sounds like you may just be looking for the "pinch-zoom scaling factor" which can be checked with [`window.visualViewport.scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VisualViewport/scale).